# Redirect page after upload stopped using Nodejs and multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am quite new in Node.js and express framework. 
I wanted to create a service to upload file where it will display the image if the file type is an image. If the file is not an image it suppose to display error message to the user. I am using multer to upload file and if the file extension doesnt match with any of the predefined extension, it will return false to stop the upload process. But somehow it doesnt redirect the page to the error page if the upload stopped. 
 Does the return false stopped the entire POST process? Is there any way for me to display error message if the upload stopped?

```
module.exports=function(app)
{
    var express=require('express');
    var multer=require('multer');
    var path=require('path');
    var fs=require('fs');
    var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
    var done = false;
    var targetPath="";

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({uploadDir: '/uploads',extended:true, keepExtensions:true}));

    app.use(function(req,res,next)
    {
        var handler = multer({ dest: './uploads/',
        rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename+Date.now();
        },
        onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        if(file.extension != 'png' && file.extension != 'jpg' && file.extension != 'jpeg' && file.extension != 'gif')
        {   
            done = false;
            return false;
        }
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
        },
        onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
        targetPath = file.path;
        done = true;
        }
        });
        handler(req, res, next);
    });

    app.get('/',function (req,res)
    {
        res.render('newindex.jade')
    });

    app.get('/errorpage', function (req,res)
    {
        res.render('errorpage.jade')
    })

    app.post('/uploads', function (req,res)
    {
        if(done = true)
        {
            console.log(req.files);
            //res.end("Image has been uploaded at " + targetPath);
            res.redirect("/" + targetPath);
            targetPath="";
            //res.send('<img src="' + targetPath + '">');
        }       
        else
        {
            res.redirect("./errorpage")
        }
     });

    app.get('/uploads/:file', function (req, res)
    {
        file = req.params.file;
        var img = fs.readFileSync("./" + "/uploads/" + file);
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(img, 'binary');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can add req, res in onFileUploadStart() and insert res.doSomething() before the line "return false;". For example:

> onFileUploadStart: function (file, req, res) {
>
> ```
>    {   
>        done = false;
>        res.json({message: "Upload failed"})
>        return false;
>    }
>    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
>    }
> ```